# Thymeleaf Date input giving current date on form submission

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Class HomeProductInfoDTO has Date field createdOn

```
import java.util.Date;
private Date createdOn;
```

products.html

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{review}" method="POST" th:object="${prod}">
<td><input type="text" name="createdOn" th:value="*{createdOn}" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="imageUrl" th:value="*{imageUrl}" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="productUrl" th:value="*{productUrl}" /></td>
```

**When trying to post "prod" without editing createdOn value, i get the value of createdOn variable as current date instead of the value which was displayed in the form.** On changing the input to some new value it works fine.
Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/review")
    public String saveProduct(@ModelAttribute(value="prod") HomeProductInfoDTO HomeProductInfoDTO, BindingResult bindingResult, 
            Model model){
```

What should i do to get the createdOn field as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using **${#dates.format(prod.createdOn,'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm')}**

```
<td><input type="text" name="createdOn" th:value="${#dates.format(prod.createdOn,'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm')}"/></td>
```